# Flutter: Passing json response to next screen

Tags: json, flutter

I'm trying to pass JSON response to the next screen but receiving the following error:

> error: The argument type 'Response' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [nutrivisor] lib/screens/scan_screen.dart:179)

Code:

```
Future<void> _clearImage() async {
    try {
      String filename = imageFile!.path.split('/').last;
      FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
        "image": await MultipartFile.fromFile(imageFile!.path,
            filename: filename, contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpg')),
        "type": "image/png"
      });
      Response response = await dio.post('http://IP:8000/scan/',
          data: formData,
          options: Options(
              followRedirects: false,
              // will not throw errors
              validateStatus: (status) => true,
              headers: {
                "accept": "*/*",
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
              }));
      print(response);
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ScanScreen2(jsondata: response)),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

Code for ScanScreen2:

```
class ScanScreen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final List jsondata;

  ScanScreen2({Key key, this.jsondata}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScanScreen2State createState() => _ScanScreen2State();
}
```

Also, after passing the response to another screen, I want to know how to use that in my next screen. Please provide the code for the same.

Comment: It would be more clearer if you can provide the code for both ScanScreen2 and from where you get the response(Eg;- method)

Comment: Hey, kindly check now @sajithlakmal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your response body contain a map;

```
Future<void> _clearImage() async {
    try {
      String filename = imageFile!.path.split('/').last;
      FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
        "image": await MultipartFile.fromFile(imageFile!.path,
            filename: filename, contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpg')),
        "type": "image/png"
      });
      Response response = await dio.post('http://IP:8000/scan/',
          data: formData,
          options: Options(
              followRedirects: false,
              // will not throw errors
              validateStatus: (status) => true,
              headers: {
                "accept": "*/*",
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
              }));
      if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response);
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ScanScreen2(jsondata: response.data!)),
      );}
      else{
       print("Some thing went wrong : responseStatusCode = ${response.statusCode}")}
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

Edit2: Op just added json data structure.

```
class ScanScreen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  // Change from List -> Map
  final Map jsondata;

  ScanScreen2({Key key, this.jsondata}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScanScreen2State createState() => _ScanScreen2State();
}
```

Comment: What is printed in the console

Comment: error: The getter 'body' isn't defined for the type 'Response<dynamic>'. (undefined_getter at [nutrivisor] lib/screens/scan_screen.dart:181)

Comment: it was my fault it is not body is is data. I have changed the answer

Comment: It gives me this error: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: Getting this error: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you wanted is the **body** of the response, looking at the error this should be fix it:

```
final json = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ScanScreen2(jsondata: json)),
      );
```

Edit: I see you are using dio package not the HTTP package, I'm not very familiar with dio but try this:

```
Response<List> response = await dio.post('http://IP:8000/scan/',
          data: formData,
          options: Options(
              followRedirects: false,
              // will not throw errors
              validateStatus: (status) => true,
              headers: {
                "accept": "*/*",
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
              }));

Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ScanScreen2(jsondata: response.data)),);}
```

Comment: Hey. It gives me following error: "error: The getter 'body' isn't defined for the type 'Response<dynamic>'."

Comment: I have edited the answer, I thought you were using http package.

Comment: Now it gives me another error! error: The argument type 'List<dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<dynamic>'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [nutrivisor] lib/screens/scan_screen.dart:181)

Comment: simply add null check by adding '!' at the front response.data, like this: response.data!

Comment: Hey, after that is shows this: DioError [DioErrorType.other]: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>?'

Comment: Well I don't know you json data structure looks like, please include one so I have enough information.

Comment: My json response: {"energi":"486","protein":"5.9","carbohydr":"71.8","sugar":"37.2","tran":"0.1","satur":"9.5"}

Comment: That's not a list at all... why do you ask for List<dynamic> then, change the data type to Map instead.

Comment: Hey, it was my bad. I'm really sorry, didn't notice it. Thank you so much.

Comment: That's fine we are all doing it sometimes.